# После заливки на хост поплыл бграунд

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Сайт [pamyatniki.com.by](http://pamyatniki.com.by) у себя проверял через xampp, денвер и в 3 браузерах перед заливкой все нормально было. Как залил на хост половина бакграундов поплыло. подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть дело?

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpamyatniki.com.by&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: укажите какие именно картинки изменились и как именно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заметил что вы неверно определили `background`:

```
.nav {
    ...
    background-image: url(img/button.png) repeat-x;
    ...
}
```

Это не сработало, т.к.  `background-image` должен содержать только путь к изображению, если вы хотите добавить `repeat-x`, то надо писать `background`:

```
.nav {
    ...
    background: url(img/button.png) repeat-x;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Поправил файл стилей! Исправил bground-image на bground и все так же(